# I get differents results with Java and Sql

Tags: sql, spring-boot

when I exec this sentence in Sql -->

```
 SELECT * from article
```

My article is :

```
Artículo {
Id:1
Nombre:'mesa'
fc_inicio : 1/7/2018
fc_fin : 31/7/2018
}

SELECT * from article where (fc_inicio <= '29/08/2019' ) and (fc_fin >= '21/02/2019')
```

I don't get nothing, Ok, it is true.

But with Java when I insert in my form , year 2010 or 2020 ... I ALWAYS  return data...

```
               result = pgService.validate(pg.getStartdatevalidity() , pg.getStartdatevalidity());

                System.out.println("da" + result);

                for (int j = 0; j < result.size(); j++) {
                    Parameter h =  result.get(j) ; 
                    System.out.println("da--2" + h.getParameter());
                }
```

Service:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from article where (fc_inicio <= :endDate ) and (fc_fin >= :startDate)", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Article> validate(@Param("startDate") Date startDate , @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

Does not matter the Date with Java I always get return data...

Comment: You havn't tagged an RDBMs - guessing Postgres from the code, nor given us data types. I would be suspicious of there being a difference between your java which is using a date typed value, vs the SQL which is using strings. Change the SQL to use a TO_DATE function with an appropriate format string and then tell us if its still different.

Comment: An additional (I think) copy paste error but `fc_fin >= '21/02/2019'` when fc_fin is `31/7/2018` is not true.

Comment: I suggest you printing out the query you get from java, expected output, output you get and, why not, some input to test on